# asp.net systemd service stuck using .net 3.1

Tags: .net, ubuntu, webserver, asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to get a systemd service set up for hosting a website on a raspberry pi. I have ubuntu 20.04 installed and have been trying to get my service running but have been finding that it is not starting because it seems it can not find the aspnetcore 3.1 runtime. Thing is, I do not want to use 3.1 and do indeed have 5.0 installed.  Below is the message i get using the code:

```
 journalctl -u   BuildItWithDan.service

Mar 07 14:02:22 ubuntu systemd[1]: BuildItWithDan.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=150/n/a
Mar 07 14:02:22 ubuntu systemd[1]: BuildItWithDan.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 07 14:02:33 ubuntu systemd[1]: BuildItWithDan.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 328.
Mar 07 14:02:33 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Running ASP.NET Core on Ubuntu 20.04 Webserver APACHE.
Mar 07 14:02:33 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Running ASP.NET Core on Ubuntu 20.04 Webserver APACHE.
Mar 07 14:02:33 ubuntu dotnet-example[7219]: It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
Mar 07 14:02:33 ubuntu dotnet-example[7219]: The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.
Mar 07 14:02:33 ubuntu dotnet-example[7219]:   - The following frameworks were found:
Mar 07 14:02:33 ubuntu dotnet-example[7219]:       5.0.3 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Mar 07 14:02:33 ubuntu dotnet-example[7219]: You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
Mar 07 14:02:33 ubuntu dotnet-example[7219]: The specified framework can be found at:
Mar 07 14:02:33 ubuntu dotnet-example[7219]:   - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=arm64&rid=ubuntu.20.04-arm64
Mar 07 14:02:33 ubuntu systemd[1]: BuildItWithDan.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=150/n/a
Mar 07 14:02:33 ubuntu systemd[1]: BuildItWithDan.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Here is my service code:

```
[Unit]
Description=Running ASP.NET Core on Ubuntu 20.04 Webserver APACHE

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/BuildItWithDan/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/BuildItWithDan/BuildItWithDan.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And my dot-net version installed.

```
dotnet --info

.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.200
 Commit:    70b3e65d53

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  20.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.20.04-arm64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.200/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.3
  Commit:  c636bbdc8a

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.200 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.3 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.3 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Any thoughts on why this service would not use the .net 5 runtime that is already installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer.

In my service had this line

```
ExecStart= /usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/BuildItWithDan/BuildItWithDan.dll
```

When it should have simply been

```
ExecStart= dotnet /var/www/BuildItWithDan/BuildItWithDan.dll
```

Basically, call 'dotnet' instead of giving it a path. silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your application was deployed as a framework-dependent application. That means it assumes framework ASP.NET Core 3.1.0 has already installed on target machine. You can fix that by:

1. Installing .NET Core 3 runtime (with ASP.NET Core)
2. Publishing application as self-contained (with framework included)
3. Publishing application using .NET 5 as target platform and keep it framework-dependent.

Options 2 & 3 available if you have access to source code.

More details about various deployment methods you can find on the documentation page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

**Warning**: I didn't try the method below on clear environment, so I'm not 100% sure it works (make backups before changing anything).

You also can use kind of 'hack' and try to edit a file `[application_name].runtimeconfig.json`. It has a content like:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netcoreapp3.1",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "3.1.0"
    }
  }
}
```

You can try to change it to:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net5.0",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "5.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

You also have to find a file `[application_name].deps.json` and change all occurences of:

```
.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1
```

to:

```
.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think we can forget about the service as of this point as i get the same thing when I run: dotnet /var/www/BuiltItWithDan/BuildItWithDan.dll

I have tried to publish specifically as .net5 as that is the only framework installed within my source code. When I try to publish as self-contained I get some other errors about a libhostpolicy.so file not being correct.  I believe I am publishing correct and all files I can find in source reference .net5

Comment: Thanks again, I think i found my issue and solved it.